# Postgres : Numeric data type with precision

Tags: postgresql, hibernate, bigdecimal

While storing value as 0 in a numeric data type with precision as 2 ,then while fetching data from  DB the value is returned as 0.00 in hibernate where as same is returned as 0 in Oracle.

Comment: There probably isn't anything wrong at all per se here.  Add the relevant Java code, point out the current behavior, and then tell us what behavior you want, and why.

Comment: So what's the problem? 0 is the same as 0.00